# Why can't I read my cookie value?

Tags: html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do some stuff with cookies. For now i am just trying to read a cookie and display the value in a popup-box using alert(value).
The tutorial I am following is : 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username

Somehow this doesn't work when I implement this into my web application. The cookie will be created, but the reading part somehow does not work. When I use Web Developer Toolbar, I can see that a cookie named 'language' is there.

This is the script block in my Index.aspx

```
function createCookie() {
    var box = document.getElementById("language");
    var value = box.options[box.selectedIndex].value;
    var name = "language";
    var days = 1;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + ";path=/;";
    document.cookie = 'language=en; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2012 20:47:11 UTC;                                   path=/'
    window.location = 'http://localhost:57688';
}

function readLanguageCookie() {
    var language = getCookie("language");
    if (language != null && language != "") {
        alert("Language is: " + language);
    } else {
        language = "en";
        if (language != null && language != "") {
            setCookie("language", language, 365);
        }
    }
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i, x, y, ARRcookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < ARRcookies.length; i++) {
        x = ARRcookies[i].substr(0, ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y = ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=") + 1);
        x = x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
        if (x == c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I try to execute the method

```
<form method="get" action="http://localhost:57688">
<label for="language">hjhj</label>
<select id="language" onchange="readLanguageCookie()">
<option value="en">English</option>
<option value="nl">Dutch</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Cookie details:

```
Name    language
Value   en
Host    localhost
Path    /
Secure  No
Expires Thu, 02 Aug 2012 20:47:11 GMT
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you getting any Javascript errors? What is happening on your side?

Comment: the popup just never shows, im not running into errors, its like the method isnt being called at all....

Comment: Ok, when I try to replicate the code you posted, i noticed that you not calling createCookie() anywhere, and that setCookie is not defined. Can you post the complete snippet of code?

Comment: i have called createCookie in a previous session, and the cookie is there, it doesnt get called in my current code

Comment: @dotNETLady - You don't have enough rep yet, but comments belong under the question. I think you'll get *enough* rep for comments at 30-50 or so. Until then, I'd refrain from posting "comment"-like answers. `:)`

Comment: I would look into a different resource; w3schools can be sketchy at times and generally is frowned upon at SO by most users. Try [Quirksmode's Cookie page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) instead. There's also [MDN's `document.cookie` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie).

Comment: What exactly "does he not do"? It's working for me, but I can see your "readLanguageCookie()" doesnt make sense. It is reading the cookie, and depending on that value, setting the cookie... [Check my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feZAC/)

Comment: Can you post the actual content of the cookie in your browser?

Comment: didn't u see this line? 
if (language != null && language != "") {
                    alert("Language is: " + language);
                }

Comment: @JaredFarrish added details to question

Comment: @DeadManWalking: I would say you'd want to change the value to the one you selected in the list..

Comment: yes normally i would do that (set the cookie in onchange), but this A TEST is just to TEST if i can READ the cookie, which isnt working. i just need to be able to READ my cookie, so i can continue my programming.

Answer (score -1):

May be the reason is hardcoded date?:

```
    document.cookie = 'language=en; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2012 20:47:11 UTC;
```

Comment: the problem is READING the cookie, i have no problems creating